What color is antimatter?
Salt (NaCl) is white. But what about anti-salt? Assuming it didn't collide with the regular matter and annihilate, and assuming I could look at it, would it also be white? Same for any material/substance. If you replaced the matter (protons, electrons, neutrons) with antimatter (anti-protons, positrons, anti-neutrons), would they be the same color, or would the color be different in any way (e.g. inverted)? Would an anti-rose be red, or what?
My guess is the color would be unchanged.

same color, photons are their own antiparticles

Given that spectra is just an imprint of change in configuration and motion of particles, the spectra at least is same.

Anti-rose is an anti-rose is an anti-rose is an anti-rose

Salt is not white.  It's transparent.  That white appearance is due to reflections off all of the small cubical surfaces.

@DavidWhite salt is white even if transparent, just as blue vitriol is blue despite being transparent. Even a smooth surface still reflects some light, which is the very reason why a bunch of grains scatters light to appear white.

@DavidWhite Respectfully, I don't think that the claim "Salt isn't white, it just looks white" makes a whole lot of sense.

@tparker, see the link.  https://crystalverse.com/sodium-chloride-crystals/

Not that the question is hard to interpret/answer as asked, but color doesn't exist in physics. There is no property of an object that causes it to be red (and if you think that the spectral reflectance of the object causes it to be a color, consider that a surface with a gray reflectance can reflect, e.g., red light under a gray illuminant; you just need the reflectance and illuminant spectra to appear sinusoidal in the visible spectrum with slightly different frequencies). So, @tparker, "Salt isn't white, it just looks white" is a pretty reasonable position.

(And in anticipation of objections, let's also remember that color is contextual, so what appears white in one scene can appear black in another depending on the illuminant and context around it. This is called color constancy, and "the dress" is just one example. Beyond that there are huge individual differences in things like photoreceptor ratios, retinal wiring, photoreceptor spectral sensitivities, etc. all through the brain. Color's a brain thing.)

Surely anti-salt would be anti-white. Whether white is different from anti-white is the real question.

This is a matter of a recent, as well as ongoing research.
So far, only antihydrogen is available in amounts that some very advanced spectroscopy is possible to run on.
So far, the results are that hydrogen and anti-hydrogen are spectrally identical - down to the accuracy of the measurements.
The accuracy in these measurements is many orders of magnitude better than the human eye spectral discrimination, meaning that if we get enough anti-hydrogen and force it to glow its red Balmer spectral series, the red hue will be exactly the same as in the normal hydrogen.
We are yet to see light from heavier anti-atoms, but we keep trying.
The modern theoretical consensus is that we will probably not find any difference at all.

p.s. Even marginal (from the current standpoint) theories that DO expect spectral differences, predict only minor differences between normal- and anti- substances, on the order of magnitude of less than what we see between different isotopes. These differences, should they exist, will also be way below human eye color precision.

A reference would be nice...

@fraxinus The experimental aspects of this answer are fine enough, but the statement of 'theoretical consensus' is incorrect. In fact it is just the opposite, the Standard Model of particle physics implies that there is a difference, see my answer below.

@SethK ok, the theoretical consensus is that the difference is VERY, VERY small. One can imagine that some heavier nuclei will have somewhat different mass or even different stable isotopes. This much.

@fraxinus Whether a physical observeable is zero versus nonzero is an incredibly important qualitative distinction between two theories. In this context this tells us whether that theory has an exact symmetry or a broken one, which informs you crucially about what the ultraviolet theory may look like. The SM with the CP-odd-phases zero is importantly qualitatively different from the observed SM with them nonzero.

Antimatter has the same electromagnetic properties as matter (due to CPT symmetry), so its atoms and solids exhibit identical energy levels and band structures, meaning an anti-object would have the same color as its matter counterpart—though forming and observing bulk antimatter is practically impossible because it annihilates upon contact with normal matter.
Edit: From a basic quantum‐electrodynamics perspective, antimatter has the same electromagnetic properties as matter and would reflect/absorb light in the same way—so, to the naked eye, an ‘anti‐metal’ should look identical in color to an ordinary metal. However, the full Standard Model is chiral, and it exhibits discrete‐symmetry violations (e.g., C and P), as shown in experiments such as the 1956 Wu experiment and 1964 kaon‐decay studies. Consequently, at extremely high precision, one would detect a slight difference in the photon spectrum from matter versus antimatter, meaning that—strictly speaking—matter is not exactly the same color as antimatter, though the difference is too small to be observed in practice.

So we simply cannot tell whether the galaxy we see in the sky is made of matter or antimatter.

It's practically impossible to create bulk anti-matter simply because it costs a literal fortune to make the stuff.

@user13964273 we certainly can. A galaxy made of antimatter would be very bright at the edges.

@Aetol would it, though? The intergalactic medium has a density of about 1 atom/m^3. It seems like that would get vaporized early on, and then leave a dead zone surrounding the galaxy that gets residual intergalactic gas at an extremely low rate.

@LawnmowerMan the intergalactic medium is quite hot. That "dead zone" would replenish pretty fast.

@Aetol I find it curious that your theorized antimatter galaxy is assumed to not be surrounded by anti-matter in it's intergalactic medium. What makes the edge of a galaxy so special?

@LawnmowerMan It would, see this question: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/40703/can-there-be-planets-stars-and-galaxies-made-of-dark-matter-or-antimatter

@candied_orange there's got to be a boundary somewhere. "Bright at the edges" is just a flippant way of putting it.

@Aetol Bright at the edges is expected, if collisions are taking place. As vast as the universe is there is no where to put this edge that it wouldn't be visible?

@candied_orange By definition, some part of the boundary would have to be directly between us and the anti-matter galaxy, so if we can see the galaxy, presumably we could see the boundary "in front of it".

@Cadence sounds right to me. But, again, why in all the vastness of space, are we certain that collisions must be taking place? I wasn't trying to place the boundary where we couldn't see it. Just where it could have some quiet alone time.

@candied_orange this has all already been discussed in the question posted above.

@Shahidul This is not true; see my answer below. The invocation of CPT is wrong and misleading.

Atomic (or molecular) transitions in anti-matter are the same as those in matter with one caveat:
They emit, absorb, reflect anti-photons, so the question reduces to: what color are anti-photons?
To the PDB! (https://pdg.lbl.gov/2022/listings/rpp2022-list-photon.pdf) where we see that the photon's quantum numbers are:
$$ I(J^{PC}) = 0,1(1^{-\,-}) $$
which means that the photon is its own anti-particle: an anti-photon is a photon.
So anti-salt looks like salt, same for anti-gold (w.r.t gold), and anti-stars or anti-galaxies or anti-CMB...and so on.

Probably the other effective answers are true enough at low energies in the setting of your question that they suffice. But for future reference, let me give a more-fundamental answer.
Quantum electrodynamics has emergent charge conjugation and parity symmetry, which is why it makes sense to talk about antiparticles at lowest order. Indeed this is quite a good emergent symmetry, so the measurement you could make with your eye of the color of an anti-metal would likely be exactly the same as that of a metal.
But these are not fundamental symmetries. Electromagnetism is a low-energy description of the physics of the Standard Model, and the Standard Model is a chiral theory. The emergent discrete symmetries of parity and charge conjugation are violated explicitly in this more fundamental theory, as we learned with the Wu experiment in 1956 and with neutral kaon decays in 1964. The Standard Model does satisfy the combined symmetry CPT (charge conjugation, parity, and time-reversal) as another answer says, but this is true of every Lorentz-invariant quantum field theory and does not address this question.
The discrete symmetry violation of the Standard Model, which we have measured through those processes, necessarily enters in every process at some order in perturbation theory. So the real answer is that while at lowest order the color would appear the same, if you very precisely measured the spectrum of the photons reflected by some material and by some anti-material, you could tell them apart. Ultimately, matter is not the same color as antimatter.
